# Dimension Fact tables issue

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, data-warehouse, star-schema-datawarehouse

Have the following Task and i don't know how to deal with:

- Orders
- Customers
- Shipments
- Warehouses

The requirements are:

- Every Order includes different products and have only one customer
- Every Customer can have more than one address and it can be Individual person or Company
- Shipments should have **Ship From** and **Ship to** address but they can be divided by different
  'Legs' Example: one shipment is going from A to B but it has to stop on C on the way so Two
  Legs.
- Each shipment consists of products that may be from different orders and for different customers
- some supplies may be partially or fully returned by customers. Returned products and the reason
  for return must be recorded.

any suggestion :(

[image]

Comment: so you described "some details" about how the data is related. But this is honestly meaningless, without the detail; "what questions are you trying to answer". Because you should structure the data so you can answer the questions you have in a performant fashion.

Comment: A process must be modeled where the customer places an order and that order must be transported to him. And i`m stuck cant move on

Comment: Those are a description of the data but not necessarily requirements. You need some actual requirements. Is the goal sales or logistics or both? You might want more than one fact table.

Comment: You still need to understand what questions are going to be asked of your model. It sounds maybe it's about logistics because you mention there may be legs in the delivery process. That's broadly irrelevant to sales. You may have a FACT_ORDER_PRODUCT_SHIPMENT_LEG that is each leg of each line of each order being shipped. But that may be overkill. It may be that the it's sufficient to model warehouse to hub to hub to warehouse to delivery. This is a Business Analysis question and I don't think it's really for Stack Overflow.